# How can I apply githook in subdirectories?

Tags: git, githooks

As far as I can see, git hook files can only be put into the root/hooks directory.

But currently, we don't have the permission of that directory.
Our project just lies in one of the subdirectories.
We just want to run some test cases before we run `git push` request, so we want to add some client-side hooks only applicable to our project directory.

Is there any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you can add any local hooks to your project.

Hooks are located under `.git/hooks`.

In your case you need to edit the `pre-push` hook and add your code.

> The `pre-push` hook runs during `git push`, **after** the remote refs have been updated but **before any objects have been transferred**.
>
> It receives the name and location of the remote as parameters, and a list of to-be-updated refs through `stdin`.
>
> You can use it to validate a set of ref updates **before a push occurs** (a non-zero exit code will abort the push).

Comment: Hi, @CodeWizard. I'm not adding local hooks to my project. I'm trying to add hook without editing files in {gitRoot}/.git/hooks because I don't have the permission of changing those files. Instead I want to find some way to add hooks in {gitRoot}/myproject/.git/hooks. I'm asking this question to find whether this is possible